# Disabled element gets focus in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, tabindex

I am using a img tag. Usually image doesn't get included in the TAB navigation flow. So i have set the "`tabindex`" attribute of img tag as 0 so that it gets included in the flow. I have disabled it. In this case, in IE, this img is not getting focused. Whereas in FF and Chrome, it gets focused though disabled. My observations is, an element with tabindex=0 , though enabled or disabled, gets included in the TAB navigation flow in webkit.

How to overcome this.

**Original code:**

```
<img id="_arrowdown" tabindex='0' src="icons/ArrowDown.png"/>
```

**Tried Fix:**

```
<img id="_arrowdown" tabindex='0' src="icons/ArrowDown.png" onFocus="if(document.getElementById('_arrowdown').disabled == true){return false;}" disabled='true'>
```

But this fix doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
img:focus {
outline-width: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8j7yehs/3/)

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8j7yehs/4/) which works for disabled `img`

Comment: I do not want the image to get focused only when it is disabled. Not always.

Comment: @Rajasri.J.. check this updated fiddle works only for disabled image http://jsfiddle.net/k8j7yehs/4/

Comment: @Rajasri.J..If it is working for you can check it is as correct. It might help some one else.

Comment: This is only visually hiding the focus! The img will stll receive focus.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `tabindex=-1` when you set `disabled`, and `tabindex=0` when the img is enabled.
This will prevent the image to be focused only when it's disabled.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `disabled` is not a valid HTML 5 attribute for `<img>` – what would it mean anyways? If you want to set custom attributes, use `data-*`, like `data-mydisabled`.

The right way to go is to set `tabindex=-1` instead.

This will remove the image from the tab flow again.